# DLLImport not working even if the file is in Bin folder

Tags: c#, .net, com, dllimport

I am using a third party application which is using DLLImport in their code. The COM DLl that they are using, they gave it to me separately.

I did put the file in the Bin/Debug folder of the third party source code and recompiled the code.

After doing that I am seeing Unable to load Module error on my application. Any ideas why it could be the case?

It is throwing following error:

```
Unable to load DLL 'QMSL_MSVC10D.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"}
```

i did run dependency walker in it and I see following errors:

```
Error: At least one required implicit or forwarded dependency was not found.
Error: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in an implicitly dependent module.
Error: Modules with different CPU types were found.
Warning: At least one delay-load dependency module was not found.
Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module.
```

My question is that how could they compile the DLL with these many errors? And what are the chances that there is ANY co-relation between the errors I am seeing and what we are seeing in Dependency walker?

Comment: Can you provide us the error message?  Without it or some other information it's going to be hard to figure out what's going wrong here

Comment: I added the error details above.

Comment: That dll has to go along with your code, rather than the third party source code. The point of a dll is that it is NOT compiled into the third party library. You must include it along side. Add it to your project and make it Contents, Copy if Newer.

Comment: I copied the assembly in my Bin folder as well. Still the same problem. On eother thing I noticed is that when i tried to add the file into my references it threw following exception`Please make sure that the file is accessible and a valid assembly or COM component`

Comment: @Californicated: You don't add it as a reference.  I think tofutim is suggesting adding it as a resource.  How it gets to the bin directory of your application is not really important until you start making your own setup package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to "DLL not found", that error message can also mean that one of the DLL's dependencies was not found, the DLL or one of its dependencies has a different architecture than the host application, or the initialization function `DllMain` returned a failure code.

Use Process Monitor to watch file activity, and check whether there's a failure opening a DLL file (which may be the one listed in the DllImport but could also be a dependency)

Based on the filename of the DLL, it sounds as if it is built against the Debug version of the C++ libraries.  It's not allowed to distribute the Debug version of the runtime library; your source needs to give you a DLL built against the release version of runtime libraries (debugging can be enabled inside their DLL, but they can't use the debug runtime).

Comment: He/she can also use [depends](http://www.dependencywalker.com/), which I've found to be a little easier to use.

Comment: @PatrickQuirk: I like Dependency Walker too, but in my experience it causes more problems with .NET applications (when profiling with the options you need to actually get useful information) than it solves.  Maybe a newer version has worked around those.

Answer (score 1):

If this is COM DLL, you need to register it with "regsvr32 name.dll".  Type it in Command Prompt and press "Enter." Replace "name.dll" with the one that you have dll.

This error also can occur if DLL has to be part of GAC and not bin folder.

Comment: If it were a COM DLL, he wouldn't be talking about `DllImport`.  They are two different interop methods.  The question is a bit confused.

Comment: OK. Probably there is a confusion here. I am using a  third party .NET project which is basically a wrapper to a c++ application called QMSL_MSVC10D.dll. They saperately gave me this file and now I am having problems loading it. Their code inside the .NET library looks like following:`[DllImport(qmslDllName, SetLastError = true, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]`

Comment: One only puts .NET assemblies in the GAC, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: I tried to put the file in GAC an dit says that it needs to have its own manifest

Comment: That means that DLL isn't GACable.

Comment: Yes, I also specified the fully Qualified path in DLLImport but it still throws the same error

Answer (score 0):

The `DllImport` works only if you are using it in a `public class` and when using the following `namespaces`:

`using System;`

`using System.Runtime;`

`using System.Runtime.InteropServices;`

Answer (score 0):

[DllImport("DLL_NAME")]

and Code :

```
    if (!Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process).Contains(HttpRuntime.BinDirectory))
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process) + ";" + HttpRuntime.BinDirectory, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
```